# How do get grid workspaces in ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: workspaces, 20.10, workspace-switcher

In previous versions ubuntu I use some extensions (Workspace grid, Workspace matrix) for getting workspace grid (3columns x 2rows of workspaces). But in 20.10 it doesn't work. How can I tune this function in 20.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After update to ubuntu 20.10, extensions has been disabled in gnome-tweak-tool. After enabled extension there, workspace matrix is worked.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The GNOME Shell extension "[Workspace Matrix](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/)" adds this feature. I've got it installed here on Ubuntu 20.10 and it works well.

[image: Screenshot of Super+W]