# How to get a grid of workspaces in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: workspaces, 22.04

In previous Ubuntu-releases, gnome shell extension could be used to get a grid of workspaces. [20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300237/how-do-get-grid-workspaces-in-ubuntu-20-10), [18.04](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/12/enable-workspace-grid-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/), ...
Up to now, these extensions are not available for Ubuntu 22.04.

Is there a way to get a grid of workspaces in Ubuntu 22.04 at the moment?

Comment: The author of Workspace Matrix [is working on it](https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix/pull/217)

Comment: Oh, great. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the gnome extension is now ready!
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/

Comment: Thank you and thanks to "mzur", the author of the extension.

Note: If you already tried to install it while it has been outdated, clicking the "update"-button within "Extensions" or within the "browser view" might be necessary. After clicking the update button, the extension can be installed.